# How to make IntelliJ IDEA highlight the implemented methods of an interface

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, kotlin, interface, highlight

In Eclipse, when I put the caret on an Interface a class is implementing, the methods are marked in the side bar by default (as small colored stripes). This way I can easily see the methods the class is implementing without having to go into the interface itself and check out what methods it contains

I haven't found anything similar in IntelliJ. Is this even possible somehow easily?

(As a side note, I use Kotlin when programming, but I assume that this feature is not found for Java either)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, you can put the caret on the "implements" keyword and press Ctrl-Shift-F7 to highlight methods implemented via an interface (if the class implements multiple interfaces, you get a popup asking you which methods to highlight). An equivalent feature for Kotlin is not implemented at this time (as of Kotlin 1.3).

In the class body, you can indeed see the interface methods highlighted by gutter icons, as the other answer says.

Comment: Nice. For Java this indeed works. If I put the caret on "implements" or "extends" all methods are highlighted at the side bar. If more than one interfaces are implemented, putting my caret on "implements" will highlight them all (Not a real problem). The CTRL+SHIFT+F7 combo does not work for me, as I have the Eclipse keymappings in use. However, your answer  "this feature is not implemented for Kotlin yet" is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: For Mac OS I use CMD+SHIFT+F7. Still waiting for the feature in Kotlin!

Answer (score 1):

Methods or properties that are overriding or implementing anything of a parent class or interface are marked next to the line numbers, finding out from which class or interface they are coming can be done by hovering over them:

[image]

Clicking on it will take you to the parent/interface definition.

The same mark, but with a downwards pointing arrow, is used in the interface/parent class and shows a list of implementations/overrides when clicked on.

All of this also works for java and scala.

Comment: Yep, but I'd still need to scroll through the whole file and wait for each tooltip to pop up, which is not convenient.